# How to pass updated data to already child vue component rendered

Tags: laravel, vue.js, components

I'm trying to update some vars into a component from parent. My situation is this:

I have a parent component:

```js
    import LugarListComponent from './LugarListComponent';
    import LugarAddComponent from './LugarAddComponent'

    export default {
        components:{
            'lugar-list-component' : LugarListComponent,
            'lugar-add-component' : LugarAddComponent,
        },
        data(){
            return {
                show: false,
                nombre: '',
                desc : '',
            }
        },
        methods:{
            showComponent: function () {
                this.show = true;
            },
            hideComponent: function () {
                this.show = false;
            },
            setLugar: function(lugar){
                this.show = true;
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            //console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
```

```html
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <h3>Lugares</h3>

        <div style="text-align: right">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" v-show="!show" v-on:click.prevent="showComponent"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Adicionar</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" v-show="show" v-on:click.prevent="hideComponent"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i> Regresar</button>
        </div>
        <br>

        <lugar-list-component v-show="!show" @setLugar="setLugar"></lugar-list-component>
        <lugar-add-component v-show="show" @hideComponent="hideComponent"></lugar-add-component>
    </div>
</template>
```

This component has two childs components, lugar-list for list places and lugar-add for add a place. I have a show var for control when I show one of this.

I want to edit a place, but I want to send data to lugar-add for show his values into this component, but I don't find any solution for update the vars into lugar-add. Here I show the code of this components.

For lugar-add

```js
export default {
        data(){
            return {
                image: '',
                nombre: '',
                desc : ''
            }
        },
        methods: {
            onImageChange(e) {
                let files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
                if (!files.length)
                    return;
                this.createImage(files[0]);
            },
            createImage(file) {
                let reader = new FileReader();
                let vm = this;
                reader.onload = (e) => {
                    vm.image = e.target.result;
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            },
            uploadImage(){
                axios.post('/lugar',{
                    image: this.image,
                    nombre: this.nombre,
                    desc: this.desc
                }).then(response => {
                    if(response.status == 200){
                        this.$emit('hideComponent')
                    }
                });
            },
            setAttributes(lugarEdit){
                console.log('disparado');
                this.nombre = lugarEdit.nombre;
                this.desc = lugarEdit.desc;
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            //console.log('Component mounted.');
            this.$on(
                'setAttributes',
                function(lugar) {
                    this.nombre = lugar.nombre;
                    this.desc = lugar.desc;
                }
            );
        }
```

```html
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Nombre</label>
            <input type="text" v-model="nombre" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre del lugar">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="descTexArea">Descripci&oacute;n</label>
            <textarea v-model="desc" class="form-control" id="descTexArea" rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Subir im&aacute;genes</label>
            <input type="file" v-on:change="onImageChange" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="uploadImage">Adicionar</button>
        </div>


        <div class="col-md-3" v-if="image">
            <img :src="image" class="img-responsive" height="70" width="90">
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Here I use event for hide this component and show the lugar-list component. Here is the code for lugar-list

```js
export default {
        name: 'lugar-list-component',
        data:function(){
            return {
                listLugares : [],
                id : '',
            }
        },
        methods:{
            getLugares: function () {
                fetch('/lugar')
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(res => {
                        this.listLugares = res;
                    })
            },
            setId: function(id){
                this.id = id;
            },
            removeLugar: function(id){
                this.id = id;
                axios.delete('lugar/'+id)
                    .then(response => {
                        this.getLugares();
                    });
            },
            editLugar: function(id){
                this.id = id;

                axios.get('lugar/'+id)
                    .then(response => {
                        this.$emit('setLugar',response);
                    });
            },
        },
        mounted() {
            this.getLugares();
        }
    }
```

```html
<template>
    <div class="container">

        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
                <th scope="col">Desc.</th>
                <th scope="col">Fecha</th>
                <th scope="col">Acciones</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr v-for="(item, index) in listLugares">
                <th scope="row">{{ index+1 }}</th>
                <td>{{ item.nombre }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.desc }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.created_at }}</td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" v-on:click.prevent="editLugar(item.id)"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Editar</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" v-on:click.prevent="removeLugar(item.id)"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i> Eliminar</button>
                </td>
            </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>


    </div>
</template>
```

I hope that you can understand me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Emit an event from the 1st child component to update parent's prop. Then pass the value you want to update as a prop to the secund child element.

Comment: I tested this. The problem is that the component really was rendered I think, I have an event into lugar-list component for to notify to parent component the place that I want to edit, "editLugar". This function trigger the setLugar function on parent, here I get the place but I don't know how I can send this new data to add component.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean here. You just want to trigger an action on the child component, or add some data to it?

If you want to add some data then you should have all the data in the parent component in a data. Then when recieving data from the first child, you append/update the parent's data. Then you pass the data (that is always up to date) from the parent to the secund child as prop. Changes to the prop will automatically be reflected in the child component.

Answer (score 0):

I don't find other solution that use routes with params, I believe that is the best solution.

Here is my routes

```js
{
        path: '/lugar', component: require('./components/lugar/LugarComponent').default,
        children: [
            { path: '', component: LugarList },
            {
                path: 'add/:id?',
                name: 'lugarAdd',
                component: LugarAdd
            },
            {
                path: 'list',
                component: LugarList
            }
        ]
    }
```

The route for Add a place has an optional param.

Now, into the Add component I get the param with this code:

```js
this.id = this.$route.params.id;
                this.modeEdit = true;

                axios.get('/lugar/'+this.id)
                    .then(response => {
                        this.nombre = response.data.nombre;
                        this.desc = response.data.desc;

                        for(let i = 0; i<response.data.images.length; i++){
                            this.image.push(response.data.images[i]);
                        }
                    });
```

When I get the place id I request for its information with axios.